# Android Checkbox enable and disable

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

I have question,

I have checkbox,that are cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4.
I want, when i checked cb1 then cb2 will be disable and cb3,cb4 keep enable, after that i checked again cb3 then cb4 will be disable too.

The 1st step it worked well, but when i try to checked cb3, then cb4 wont be disable.
there is my code

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View v){

    CheckBox cb1= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    CheckBox cb2= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    CheckBox cb3= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb3);
    CheckBox cb4= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb4);


    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.cb1:
        if (cb1.isChecked()) {
            cb2.setEnabled(false);

        }else {
            cb2.setEnabled(true);


        }

        break;

    //......
```

please help me guys!!

Update Question:

**what i mean, something like this,I have a 10 checkboxes, when I was checking one of them, then the number of checkboxes that can be checked turned into 5, then when one of these 5 checkbox is checked, then it will be reduced again to 2 checkbox where is enable to be checked, will be like that until there are no more checkboxes can be checked**

Comment: I think you need to use radio button instead

Comment: By "disabled" do you actually mean "unchecked" or really disabled, like "non-clickable" ? If latter is the case, then please provide code where you try to disable `cb4` when checking `cb3`.

Comment: Use Radio group button instead.

Comment: based on your update: then what is the procedure for the user to go back from "no more checkboxes can be checked" back to 10 checkboxes ?

Comment: the procedure is, at the time of the last checkbox is checked turned into unchecked, it would make a disable checkbox back into enable checkbox, when no more checkbox is checked, then all of 10 checkbox will be enable to checked

Comment: to: kiruwka
i mean non-clickable, the answer you give before actually right, but i didt know where should i put the next code to disable cb4 when i checked cb3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this

```
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.cb1:
    if (cb1.isChecked()) {
        cb2.setChecked(false);
    }else {
        cb2.setChecked(true);


    }

    break;
```

Comment: what i mean, something like this,I have a 10 checkboxes, when I was checking one of them, then the number of checkboxes that can be checked turned into 5, then when one of these 5 checkbox is checked, then it will be reduced again to 2 checkbox where is enable to be checked, will be like that until there are no more checkboxes can be checked